# MySQL in clause to Enumeration Path on Table Heirachy

Tags: mysql, nested, set, hierarchy

I had some investigation into using MySQL with Hierarchical data, (currently my table uses an adjacency list model) so I am getting a breadcrumb via a loop sending the parent id back and re-cursing the same function in PHP, but this fires a query each time. So now I want improve by creating a _construct method to fire a query once and return an object I can just refer to.

To do this I have done some research into Nested Sets, Path Enumeration (Materialized Path) and Closure Table.

I have chosen the Materialised Path.

My SQL

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM menu t1
WHERE t1.menu_id IN (
    SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(t2.Lineage,'/',',')) as CAT_IDD
    FROM menu t2
    WHERE t2.page_id = 52
)
```

My Table is such, I'll paste in the dump so you can test it...

STRUCTURE

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu` (
  `menu_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `menu_text` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NEW !!!',
  `menu_alt_text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `menu_alt_location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `page_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `parent_menu_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lineage` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `menu_display_order` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `menu_display` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `site_short_code` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DEFAULT',
  `menu_can_delete` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `opens_in_new_window` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   PRIMARY KEY (`menu_id`),
   KEY `site_short_codee` (`site_short_code`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='This displays the menu/navigation of the site' AUTO_INCREMENT=75 ;
```

INSERT THE DATA

```
INSERT INTO `menu` (`menu_id`, `menu_text`, `menu_alt_text`, `menu_alt_location`, `page_id`, `parent_menu_id`, `lineage`, `menu_display_order`, `menu_display`, `site_short_code`, `menu_can_delete`, `user_id`, `opens_in_new_window`)    
VALUES (1, 'Home', 'opens in same window', 'none', 1, 0, '0', 1, 1, 'site1', 0, 0, 0),
(41, 'About Us', 'About Us, opens in same window', 'none', 42, 0, '0', 4, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(42, 'Menu 3', 'Menu 3, opens in same window', 'none', 43, 0, '0', 30, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(43, 'Menu 4', 'Menu 4 templates, opens in same window', 'none', 44, 42, '1/42', 9, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(44, 'Menu 5', 'Menu 5, opens in same window', 'none', 45, 42, '1/42', 3, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(45, 'Menn 6', 'Menu 6, opens in same window', 'none', 46, 42, '1/42', 6, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(46, 'Menu 7', 'Menu 7, opens in same window', 'none', 47, 0, '0', 43, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(47, 'Menu 8', 'Menu 8, opens in same window', 'none', 48, 46, '1/46', 3, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(48, 'Menu 9', 'Menu 9, opens in same window', 'none', 50, 46, '1/46', 6, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(49, 'Menu 10', 'Menu 10, opens in same window', 'none', 53, 48, '1/46/48', 9, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(50, 'Menu 11', 'Menu 11, opens in same window', 'none', 49, 46, '1/46', 12, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(51, 'Menu 12', 'Menu 12, opens in same window', 'none', 51, 48, '1/46/48', 15, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(52, 'Menu 13', 'Menu 13, opens in same window', 'none', 52, 48, '1/46/48', 18, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(53, 'Menu 14, 'Menu 14, opens in same window', 'none', 70, 0, '0', 7, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(54, 'Release Dates', 'Release Dates, opens in same window', 'none', 56, 53, '1/53', 12, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(55, 'Clients', 'Clients, opens in same window', 'none', 57, 0, '0', 65, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(56, 'Menu 145 Clients', 'Menu 145 clients, opens in same window', 'none', 74, 55, '1/55', 3, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0),
(57, 'ffff', 'ffff, opens in same window', 'none', 59, 55, '1/55', 6, 1, 'site1', 1, 43, 0);
```

This will return a list of menu_ids in the linage

```
    SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(t2.Lineage,'/',',')) as CAT_IDD
    FROM menu t2
    WHERE t2.page_id = 52
```

However when used as a subquery above it only returns 1 row. I need it to return 3.
I've tried using an nest JOIN too...

Hmmm any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Andi

------ EDIT Answering own question

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM menu t1, menu t2
WHERE 
t2.page_id = 52
AND
FIND_IN_SET (
      t1.menu_id, t2.Lineage
)
```

This seems to work for me...
If this helps anyone else I hope so. i changed the delimiter to a comma

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think this works find to find the history...

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM menu t1, menu t2
WHERE 
t2.page_id = 52
AND
FIND_IN_SET (
     t1.menu_id, t2.Lineage
)
```

If this helps anyone else I hope so. i changed the delimiter to a comma in the data in the lineage field...

Thanks